# How do I json.Unmarshal based on a type

Tags: go

I am writing a go client for the Flowdock API. Their API for Message has a number of attributes two of which are `Event` and `Content`

When `Event = message` then `Content` is a string. When `Event = comment` `Content` is a JSON object.

I want to defer unmarhsalling `Content` until it is needed. To do this I map `RawContent` in my struct and define a `Content()` method on `Message` to return the correct object.

Here is the code to illustrate:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

// Message represents a Flowdock chat message.
type Message struct {
    Event            *string          `json:"event,omitempty"`
    RawContent       *json.RawMessage `json:"content,omitempty"`
}


func (m *Message) Content() (content interface{}) {
    // when m.Event is a message the RawContent is a string
    // real code handles unmarshaling other types (removed for this example)
    return string(*m.RawContent)
}

func main() {
    var message = &Message{}
    rawJSON := `{"event": "message", "content": "Howdy-Doo @Jackie #awesome"}`
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(rawJSON), &message); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    event := "message"
    rawMessage := json.RawMessage("Howdy-Doo @Jackie #awesome")
    want := &Message{
        Event: &event,
        RawContent: &rawMessage,
    }

    fmt.Println(message.Content(), want.Content())
}
```

The result of running this is: http://play.golang.org/p/eds_AA6Aay

```
"Howdy-Doo @Jackie #awesome" Howdy-Doo @Jackie #awesome
```

Note: message.Content() and want.Content() are different!

At first I did not expect the quotes to be included in message but it makes sense because of how the JSON is parsed. It is just a slice of the whole `rawJSON` string.

So my questions are:

1. Should I just strip off the quotes?
2. If so what is the simplest way in Go to strip?  maybe this: http://play.golang.org/p/kn8XKOqF0z lines(6, 19)?
3. Is this even the right approach to handling JSON that can have different types for the same attribute?

Here is a more complete example showing how I handle a JSON `RawContent`: http://play.golang.org/p/vrBJ5RYcql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1:**

No, you should json.Unmarshal the content also when it only contains a string. Apart from the quotes, JSON strings may also contain backslash-escaped control characters.

**Question 2:**

Because of the answer in Question 1, do the following for the "message" case:

```
var s string        
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(*m.RawContent), &s); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
return s
```

**Question 3:**

It is a good approach to Unmarshal the event type string and use `RawMessage` to store the rest of the JSON until you've evaluated the type and know what kind of structure the content has.

You might want to consider also having a specific type also for just simple string contents, eg.:

```
type MessageContent string
```

This way you are free to implement methods on the type, allowing the Content method to return some other interface than just the empty interface{}.

**Note:**

Beware that, if you also json.Unmarshal the message string as I suggested, your Playground example will panic when trying to Unmarshal your non-quoted want.RawContent string, because it is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I had tried your answer to 2 before but the problem is that the string is not valid JSON so it cannot be unmarshalled. Here is an example http://play.golang.org/p/I5MBnMEpC5 that breaks.

Comment: That was my point with the *Note*; Your original `rawJSON`is correct JSON, and Unmarshalling it into the `Message` struct will set `RawContent` to a correct JSON string. But the non-quoted string that you put into `rawMessage` is not JSON, and therefore it will generate an error when Unmarshalled. See this [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HRtN4iJnZT)

Comment: Oh yeah! So I got the panic but thought it was the message not want for some reason - thanks a lot